# How to document properties of a function and functional constructors in jsdoc?

Tags: javascript, methods, properties, closures, jsdoc

For example how would I document this?

`var f = function () { var g = function() {}; g.h = function(); return g; }`

This isn't a pattern I've invented. See http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link out](http://usejsdoc.org/). Very helpful reference.

Do something like this.

```
/** 

*@method 
*@param

* {string} parameterA used to process..... 
* @description 
* function is used to process...... 
*/
```

Params is for parameters mentioning its type. Description describes what the function does.

```
function a(parameterA){}
```

Comment: I've read the documentation. It seems more geared towards documenting prototypal constructors and I couldn't work out the answer by myself.

Comment: Do something like this 

/** 
* ^method
* ^param 
* {string} parameterA used to process.....
* ^description 
*  function is used to process......
*/
 params is for parameters mentioning type
description describes the function 

function a(parameterA){

}
replace ^ with @ . Stackoverflow does'nt allow @....somthing

Comment: please rewrite this as an answer using backticks for pieces of source.